Ubuntu audio with Audient iD44 MKII stopped working
I recently (~half a year ago) got back to Linux after a long break. I have an Audient iD44 MKII audio interface and until yesterday it worked "plug-n-play". Today I did an update which seems to have broken things.
First some possibly critical information:

Lenovo ThinkBook 16p Gen 4
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Kernel 6.5.0-44-generic
GNOME 42.9

I no longer have the option for Audient iD44 stereo analog output available in my Ubuntu Sound settings. In fact, I only had my laptop input and output (sof-hda-dsp) and HDMI monitor output (HDMI/DisplayPort - HDA NVidia) available.
Now I've been going into rabbit hole of ALSA, Pulseaudio (which I was somewhat familiar with), and PipeWire (which is completely new to me) documentation and forum posts online with no luck.
After looking into things, removing, reinstalling and restarting pipewire I got Multichannel Audient input and output (Audient iD44 Multichannel) to appear for a while (it's again gone), but still no stereo analog output, which was there before the update.
inxi -aA shows the following:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: Lenovo driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    alternate: snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl bus-ID: 00:1f.3
    chip-ID: 8086:51ca class-ID: 0401
  Device-2: NVIDIA vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie:
    gen: 3 speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 8 link-max: gen: 4 speed: 16 GT/s
    bus-ID: 01:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:22be class-ID: 0403
  Device-3: Audient iD44 type: USB driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid
    bus-ID: 3-9.4:9 chip-ID: 2708:000b class-ID: fe01
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.5.0-44-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: no
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 1.0.7 running: yes

aplay -l gives me:
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: iD44 [Audient iD44], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 1: HDA Digital (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

With pactl list cards I can see the following:
Name: alsa_card.usb-Audient_Audient_iD44-00
Driver: alsa
Owner Module: n/a
Properties:
api.acp.auto-port = "false"
api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
api.alsa.card = "1"
api.alsa.card.longname = "Audient Audient iD44 at usb-0000:00:14.0-9.4, high speed"
api.alsa.card.name = "Audient iD44"
api.alsa.path = "hw:1"
api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio1"
device.api = "alsa"
device.bus = "usb"
device.bus-id = "usb-Audient_Audient_iD44-00"
device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:9.4:1.0"
device.description = "Audient iD44"
device.enum.api = "udev"
device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-usb"
device.name = "alsa_card.usb-Audient_Audient_iD44-00"
device.nick = "Audient iD44"
device.plugged.usec = "5350297026"
device.product.id = "0x000b"
device.product.name = "Audient iD44"
device.serial = "Audient_Audient_iD44"
device.subsystem = "sound"
sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-9/3-9.4/3-9.4:1.0/sound/card1"
device.vendor.id = "0x2708"
device.vendor.name = "Audient"
media.class = "Audio/Device"
factory.id = "14"
client.id = "36"
object.id = "105"
object.serial = "116"
object.path = "alsa:pcm:1"
alsa.card = "1"
alsa.card_name = "Audient iD44"
alsa.long_card_name = "Audient Audient iD44 at usb-0000:00:14.0-9.4, high speed"
alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
alsa.mixer_name = "USB Mixer"
alsa.components = "USB2708:000b"
alsa.id = "iD44"
device.string = "1"
Profiles:
off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
output:multichannel-output+input:multichannel-input: Multichannel Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 101, available: yes)
output:multichannel-output: Multichannel Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: yes)
pro-audio: Pro Audio (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1, available: yes)
input:multichannel-input: Multichannel Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 1, available: yes)
Active Profile: input:multichannel-input

With pactl list sinks I can see the internal audio and the HDMI sinks, but nothing with the Audient. Should a stereo analog sink be configured for the Audient? How and where? Or is there something else missing?
I tried to add Virtual Sinks for the Audient Pro-Audio as per here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Virtual-Devices#virtual-sinks
and here https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/wahggl/wireplumber_remap_usb_audio_interface/
I could then see the output in the Ubuntu Sound settings, but no sound... In fact, after setting up Pro-Audio in pavucontrol for the Audient, even the integrated sound didn't work.
I also tried removing an reinstalling alsa, pipewire, pulseaudio, pipewire-alsa, pipewire-pulse, wireplumber and tried with older kernel (6.5.0-41 and 6.5.0-35) but those didn't want to even boot correctly...
After faffing about the whole day pactl list cards doesn't show
output:multichannel-output+input:multichannel-input: Multichannel Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 101, available: yes)
output:multichannel-output: Multichannel Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: yes)
input:multichannel-input: Multichannel Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 1, available: yes)

anymore under Profiles (only pro-audio and off remain)...

I got help for the problem elsewhere. Just linking to the discussion, if anyone searches and finds this:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2499185
